# how to add a reference of a user control in a xaml file which is shared by two projects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have created a class library(CustomMapControl) in the solution and inside this class library I create a UserControl(MapItemsControl).

Now, I added a reference of this class library to both projects (Portogruaro & Trieste).

Here is my solution structure.
[image]

Portogruaro is the main project and has all files, Trieste has almost all the files which Portogruaro have added as a reference.

So, the problem is when I tried to use the CustomMapControl and drag and drop it in xaml from toolbox it doenst build and give this error

> the name "MapsItemControl" doesnt exist in namespace "clr-namespace:CustomMapControl"

And sometimes it shows this error

> Element is already a child of another element

Here is the xaml namespace

```
 xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:CustomMapControl"
```

and this is the user control in xaml

```
 <cc:MapItemsControl />      <cc:MapItemsControl />
```

The error changes when I open xaml file from different projects.
The xaml file in which I want to have this UserControl is also shared between the two projects.
I am quite sure that this is a referencing issue. 

I have no idea how to reference the CustomMapControl so it will work for both the projects.

Comment: Is the target platform(AnyCPU, x86) is same on both projects?

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah Yes it is same for both projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a problem with how your namespace is added in your wpf project. Instead of:

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:CustomMapControl"
```

try this:

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:CustomMapControl;assembly=CustomMapControl"
```

Comment: no it doesnt work...by trying this it shows this error "Element is already a child of another element"

Comment: Then I am afraid you need to post more code - especially of Form where you add your control.

Comment: I have put all the necessary code, i mean i dont think there is any more thing to show....because this is just a really simple user control....i have did it before, but with these two projects I cant make it running.

Comment: If you feel so then ok. I am unable to say anything more without seeing more code. Normally this works.

Comment: please can you explain, what code you need to see ?

Comment: i have created the new user control from scratch and add use your specified code for namespace and it worked :) . thanks

Comment: That is good :) As you see mistake was hidden in something else than posted code :)

Comment: Actually, I have already created a user control with the same name in one of the project...and that was not completely removed. So this was also causing the issue plus that complete assembly reference was also required.